# How to create a plugin for handsontable

Tags: plugins, handsontable

I want to create a plugin for handsontable and copied the removeRow files in extenstions subfolder to *jquery.handsontable.myPlugin.[js|css]*. 
In those files I renamed every occasion of **removeRow** to **myPlugin** and **RemoveRow** to MyPlugin.

In the table definition I have added `myPlugin: true`.

But the plugin (which still should show the column with button to delete the rows) is not called.

I have added a `console.log("init (removeRow)")` and `console.log("init (myPlugin)")`
in both plugins in the init().
It seems that only the *removeRow* plugin is called bun not *myPlugin*.

Do I have to register the plugin somehow to handsontable?
I assumed placing both file into the extension folder should be sufficient.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve by renaming removeRow to myPlugin, but have a look at [Callbacks and Handsontable.PluginHooks](http://docs.handsontable.com/tutorial-callbacks.html)

```
var hooks = Handsontable.PluginHooks.hooks;
```

Use this for your plugin to add hooks

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I can't try this out, as I moved from handsontable to *datatables* already.